# jquery return from post

Tags: jquery

i have jQuery script:

```
var order = 'user=lolalola';
$.post("ajax.php",{action:"run"}, order, function(data){
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
     $("#dd_message").html(data);
});
```

and php scitp:

```
<?php
echo 'php file';
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Why jquery no run php script?
Return full php code:

```
<?php
    echo 'php file';
    print_r($_POST);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `order` param? Callback should go as third parameter: look at [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Unless order is the name of function defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra parameter there. You should be getting a JS error on the browser. try this:

```
var order = 'user=lolalola';
$.post("ajax.php",{action:"run", user:"lolalola"}, function(data){
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
     $("#dd_message").html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All the POST fields should be in 1 parameter.

```
var order = 'user=lolalola';
$.post("ajax.php",'action=run&'+order, function(data){
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
     $("#dd_message").html(data);
});
```